# Integrated Windows authentication without the browsers login prompt using express / nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, iisnode

I need to get the user information from the HTTP `request` object for a node application running on Windows.  I know there's `node-sspi` npm package but is it possible to use it without prompting the users to log in via the browser's native login prompt window?  I tried hosting the node application in IIS using iisnode but the login prompt only goes away in IE.  Ideally, I would like a solution that can work across different browsers.

This is my iisnode web.config

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="iisnode" path="hello.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>
    <iisnode promoteServerVars="AUTH_USER,AUTH_TYPE" />
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="myapp">
          <match url="myapp/*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="hello.js" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This is the simple express web server that prompts the user to login when browsing in Chrome or Firefox

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express.createServer();

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  var nodeSSPI = require('node-sspi')
  var nodeSSPIObj = new nodeSSPI({
    retrieveGroups: true,
    offerBasic: true
  })
  nodeSSPIObj.authenticate(req, res, function (err) {
    res.finished || next()
  })
});

app.get('/node/express/myapp/foo', function (req, res) {
  res.send('req.connection.user = ' + req.connection.user);
});

app.get('/node/express/myapp/bar', function (req, res) {
  res.send('req.headers = ' + JSON.stringify(req.headers));
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

Comment: Hello, were you ever able to solve this? I am having the same issues.